# Can ING with would be used

Tags: gerunds

1. I miss going out with my friends
2. I miss to go out with my friends.
   According to this https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Dxt-xAK6Fb0
   1 is correct. Now I want to know which one is correct if we use 'would'
3. I think I would miss going out with my friends.
4. I think I would miss to go out with my friends.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples 2. and 4. with the infinitival clause "to go out ..." are ungrammatical because the clause can't satisfy the complement requirements of "miss", which requires a gerund-participial clause as in 1. and 3.

Comment: How to know which verbs require gerund?

Comment: The only way is to familiarise yourself with the various constructions by reading English publications as much as you can.

Comment: Does love works the same way 7. I would love reading that book. 8. I would love to read that book

Comment: No, @Rocky. _Love_ can take an infinitival complement **or** an -ing complement. **But**, 7 is not idiomatic, because an -ing complement with _love_ has a general sense, not a specific one, so "I love reading that book" implies that I often read that book. This makes "I would love reading that book" unlikely: I think it would only be used in a hypothetical, such as "if I were alone on a desert island I would love reading that book, but as it is I've never had the time to get into it."

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @Rocky I agree with Colin. Your example 7. is grammatically OK , but not natural except in certain contexts. 8. is fine.